# inner joining multiple table but mysql_query is not working

Tags: php, mysql

```
<div class="article-container">
    <?php
    $Nama=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['title']);
    //$sql="select * from peserta where Nama='$Nama'";
    $sql = "select peserta.ID_Peserta,hakim.ID_Hakim,acara.ID_Badminton,admin.ID_Admin 
                from (((peserta 
                inner join hakim on peserta.ID_Hakim=hakim.ID_Hakim)
                inner join acara on peserta.ID_Badminton=acara.ID_Badminton)
                inner join admin on peserta.ID_Admin=admin.ID_Admin"; 
    $searchresult=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from peserta where Nama='$Nama'",$sql);
    $queryResults=mysqli_num_rows($searchresult);

    if($queryResults>0){
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($searchresult)){
            echo"<div class='article-box'>
            <h3>".$row['Nama']."</h3>
            <p>".$row['ID_Peserta']."</p>
            <p>".$row['noKP']."</p>
            <p>".$row['Kelas']."</p>
            <p>".$row['Keseluruhan_Markah']."</p>
            <p>".$row['Ranking']."</p>
            <p>".$row['ID_Hakim']."</p>
            <p>".$row['ID_Badminton']."</p>
            <p>".$row['ID_Admin']."</p>

            </div>";
        }
        
    }else{
        echo "There are no results matching your search!";
    }
```

been looking forward to linking 3 different tables using the ID into my 'peserta' table but there is an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_query(): Argument #3 ($result_mode) must be of type int, string given in D:\Other\xampp\htdocs\project\article.php:25 Stack trace: #0 D:\Other\xampp\htdocs\project\article.php(25): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'select * from p...', 'select peserta....') #1 {main} thrown in D:\Other\xampp\htdocs\project\article.php on line 25

this is a school project of mine and im new to php so any help will be appreciated

Comment: _"Argument #3 must be of type int, string given"_ The [doc page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) tells you what the function expects for its arguments.

Comment: i dont really understand what should i do here cause it says 
>Parse error: syntax error, unexpected variable "$sql", expecting ")" 
after i changed it to 
```$searchresult=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from peserta where Nama='$Nama'",string $sql);```

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid MySQL query, I mean look at `from (((peserta ...`, you have 3 opening parentheses but only 2 closing parentheses. [See this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=32f6a83131a3e328ba0515c8454da9dc)

Comment: i tried adding the ) behind it but still the same error
>Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_query(): Argument #3 ($result_mode) must be of type int, string given 
but if i add string behind $sql the error become
>Parse error: syntax error, unexpected variable "$sql", expecting ")"

Comment: `$searchresult=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from peserta where Nama='$Nama'",$sql);` is incorrect. Are you are trying to join the query seen here with the variable `$sql` and then run that as the actual query?

Comment: yes i am 
```echo"<a href='article.php?title=".$row['Nama']."'><div class='article-box'>```
and this is in the search  page before entering the page that print out the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a guess from looking at what I think you are trying to do based upon the question title and the incorrect structuring of the sql query perhaps the following is appropriate?

```
<div class="article-container">
    <?php
        if( isset( $_GET['title'] ) ){
            $sql='select 
                p.ID_Peserta,
                p.Nama,
                p.noKP,
                p.Kelas,
                p.Keseluruhan_Markah,
                p.Ranking,
                h.ID_Hakim,
                a.ID_Badminton,
                ad.ID_Admin 
            from peserta p
                inner join hakim h on p.ID_Hakim=h.ID_Hakim
                inner join acara a on p.ID_Badminton=a.ID_Badminton
                inner join admin ad on p.ID_Admin=ad.ID_Admin
            where p.Nama=?';


            $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bind_param( 's', $_GET['title'] );
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result( $idp, $nama, $nokp, $kelas, $kesmar, $rank, $idh, $idb, $ida );

            while( $stmt->fetch() )printf(
                '<div class="article-box">
                    <h3>%s</h3>
                    <p>%s</p>
                    <p>%s</p>
                    <p>%s</p>
                    <p>%s</p>
                    <p>%s</p>
                    <p>%s</p>
                    <p>%s</p>
                    <p>%s</p>
                </div>', 
                $nama, $idp, $nokp, $kelas, $kesmar, $rank, $idh, $idb, $ida );
            
            $stmt->free_result();
            $stmt->close();
            
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

---

To test that the SQL query returns a result try running the following in either the GUI or from the mySQL commandline:

```
select 
    p.ID_Peserta,
    p.Nama,
    p.noKP,
    p.Kelas,
    p.Keseluruhan_Markah,
    p.Ranking,
    h.ID_Hakim,
    a.ID_Badminton,
    ad.ID_Admin 
from peserta p
    inner join hakim h on p.ID_Hakim=h.ID_Hakim
    inner join acara a on p.ID_Badminton=a.ID_Badminton
    inner join admin ad on p.ID_Admin=ad.ID_Admin
where p.Nama="<<< SUBSTITUTE A TITLE HERE >>>"
```

for instance:

```
select 
    p.ID_Peserta,
    p.Nama,
    p.noKP,
    p.Kelas,
    p.Keseluruhan_Markah,
    p.Ranking,
    h.ID_Hakim,
    a.ID_Badminton,
    ad.ID_Admin 
from peserta p
    inner join hakim h on p.ID_Hakim=h.ID_Hakim
    inner join acara a on p.ID_Badminton=a.ID_Badminton
    inner join admin ad on p.ID_Admin=ad.ID_Admin
where p.Nama="banana" <----- the title/$_GET['title'] value appears in your db???
```

Comment: emmm it only print out the ID that i listed in my table instead of listing out the name of it

Comment: firstly though does the query return a recordset if you were to run it in a gui or commandline?

Comment: i run it in mysql but i got the ID instead of the name

Comment: you mean that SQL command ONLY returns an ID and **not** the other fields when you run that in GUI/cmdline? Copy the query and replace `?` for the actual `title` you get in your hyperlink

Comment: i replace the ```?``` with ```title``` but i got this
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool`

Comment: I mean to test the sql you run it in the GUI or from command line with, for instance, `p.Nama="my title"`

Comment: i run it in sql and i got this `#1054 - Unknown column 'title' in 'where clause'`

Comment: where is `title` coming from in the where clause? there isn't a column called `title` in any of the code I posted

Comment: i added `title` in `where p.Nama=title`

Comment: ok i got the attribute from my table after this
`select p.ID_Peserta, p.Nama, p.noKP, p.Kelas, p.Keseluruhan_Markah, p.Ranking, h.ID_Hakim, a.ID_Badminton, ad.ID_Admin from peserta p inner join hakim h on p.ID_Hakim=h.ID_Hakim inner join acara a on p.ID_Badminton=a.ID_Badminton inner join admin ad on p.ID_Admin=ad.ID_Admin where p.Nama="banana";`

Comment: hey man sry for the trouble cause im new and tryin my best to learn.

Comment: i run it in sql with `p.Nama="Nama"` and i got the peserta table

Comment: The point is that you want to find items from the primary table `peserta` after you have made joins to other tables where `Nama` is one of the values in that column within the `peserta` table. If there is a record in the `peserta` table where `Nama="Nama"` then good, otherwise select a nama that **DOES** exist and test the sql query with **that** value

Comment: :-) excellent! How did you finally get this fixed?

Comment: I'm kinda confused at first, but then I realized all I need to do is change the select `ID` to the `name` from the other table I want to join. for exp: `h.ID_Hakim` to `h.Name_Hakim`. it's kinda funny how dumb I am when I figured it out haha. Anyway, thanks again for the help!